# AnimationDrawable memory usage

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an application where the first activity displays a loading animation, and it seems to increase the memory usage dramatically - with the animation the app is using around 30MB, and without it less than 10MB.

The relevant code is as follows:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.load_application);
     StartLoadingAnimation();
}

private void StartLoadingAnimation()
{
    frameAnimation = new AnimationDrawable();
    for(int i = 1; i <= 64; i++)
    {
        String index = i < 10 ? "00" + i : "0" + i; 
        int frameIdentifier = getResources().getIdentifier("loading_icon_" + index, "drawable", getPackageName());
        frameAnimation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(frameIdentifier), 70);
    }

    ImageView imageCafeLoading = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageCafeLoading);
    imageCafeLoading.setBackgroundDrawable(frameAnimation);
    imageCafeLoading.post(new LoadingImageStarter());
}

/** Starting the loading image animation */
private class LoadingImageStarter implements Runnable 
{
       public void run() 
       {
            frameAnimation.setOneShot(false);
            frameAnimation.start();
       }
}
```

It seems like finishing the activity when navigating to the next one doesn't matter, the memory usage is still much higher with the animation.

How can I release this memory when navigating away from the activity or destroying it?

Comment: You could stop, and null frameAnimation in the onPause() (this way the GC collects it at some point), and recreate and restart it in the onResume()

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference - even if I add `frameAnimation.stop(); frameAnimation = null;` right after `frameAnimation.start();`, the memory does not seem to be released.

Comment: Well, you could run System.gc() right after you set your frameAnimation to null, but its highly not advised.

Comment: If it is not an interactive animation , you should probably convert the animation into a video and load it in videoview to avoid this problem.