# Is there anyway to auto-create a drawable xml automatically from a list of images?

Tags: android

I have a frame animation that has over 150 frames, but I need to define them inside a drawable XML like this for example:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel0" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel1" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel2" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel3" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel4" android:duration="50" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wheel5" android:duration="50" />
</animation-list>
```

Other than using search and replace, is there any easier way I could define these drawable frames?

Comment: create an AnimationDrawable in your code

Comment: Yes, you are right, I did the same for iOS not sure why I'm trying this way.

Comment: I'm using the 'programatical' way:  see here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916319/animationdrawable-memory-usage